# Leetcode #217 Contains Duplicate - what is wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x

[Problem 217: Contains Duplicate](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/description/)

> Problem Description:
>
> Given an array of integers, find if the array contains any duplicates.
>   Your function should return true if any value appears at least twice
>   in the array, and it should return false if every element is distinct.

My solution in Python:

```
class Solution:
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """

        from functools import reduce
        if len(nums) < 2:
            return False
        else:
            return bool(reduce(lambda x, y: not (bool(nums.count(x) == 1) and bool(nums.count(y) == 1)), nums))
```

I thought using an `and` operation between every judgement `nums.count(x) == 1` for `x` in `nums` could derive the inverse of the answer the problem wanted, but it seems cannot get it work.

Could anyone tell me why it is wrong? For example when input is `[1, 2, 3]` I got output of `True` instead of `False`.

Is my idea totally wrong in the first place or I did the feasible implement wrongly somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `return len(set(nums)) != len(nums)` should do it - far easier then yours.

Comment: yes I got the easier one online but still wanna know how to make mine work... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reduce onyl compares pair-wise:

from the doc:

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [1,2,3,4,5]) ==  ((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)
```

Your reduce produces a boolean as output. Applied to [1,2,3,4,5] this would lead to

```
not (bool(nums.count(1) == 1) and bool(nums.count(2) == 1)), nums) = False
not (bool(nums.count(False) == 1) and bool(nums.count(3) == 1)), nums) = True 
not (bool(nums.count(True) == 1) and bool(nums.count(4) == 1)), nums) = True 
not (bool(nums.count(True) == 1) and bool(nums.count(5) == 1)), nums) = True 
           #        ^^^^^^ always 0 ==> so reduce is always True
```

reduce only compares pair wise, therefore it is not suited to the task at hand: `[1,2,3,4,2]`

```
def dupes3(nums):
    return sorted( nums.count(x) for x in nums)[-1] > 1  

def dupes2(nums):
    from collections import Counter 
    return Counter(nums).most_common()[0][1]>1

def dupes(nums): # imho easiest one
    return len(set(nums)) < len(nums)
```

Comment: then what if I put the `not` outside: `return not bool(reduce(lambda x, y: bool(nums.count(x) == 1) and bool(nums.count(y) == 1), nums))`

Comment: @Zhengyan the result of your lambda is still a bool, when searching that in the next step is is not found in your list and it will be false all the time.

Comment: Sorry I still don't see why `return reduce(lambda x, y : x ^ y, nums)` works for Leetcode  #136 Single Number: "Given an array of integers, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one."

Comment: @Zhengyan `^` is bitwise xor - it returns a number and is commutative. 6 ^9 ^6 ^9 = 0 as soon as one number is in twice it will stick out at rest. See https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number/discuss/42997/My-O(n)-solution-using-XOR/41537. Just wait a few days, maybe somebody will help you with a valid reduce option for that one

Comment: Finally I understood the difference between the two problems after looked into how `reduce` works (it uses the result of the first two elements together with the third one and my result of first two element is a bool, which is of course not in the list)... Thank you again for your patience, you really helped a lot with my big confusion today!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution(object):
    def containsDuplicate(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if len(set(nums)) == len(nums):
            return False
        return True
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, it does not answer the question what's wrong. Better [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.